# How to get a value from JSONObject in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, jwt

I have a node js app. I use JSON web token for authentication. I split my token as 3 parts (header, payload, signature) to use them for a spesific code.

My payload JSON object is as shown in the below:

```
 payload= {"email": "minnela@gmail.com", "iat" : "23254324", "exp": "4323456"}
```

I need to get the value of "email". How can I get it in Node.js?

Comment: ``payload.email ``? Also it's a terrible idea to put the password in a json webtoken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Easiest ways: `const payloadEmail=payload.email //minnela@gmail.com`

Using ES6 feature : `const {email} = payload  //minnela@gmail.com`

Using JS inbuild method that converts object to array :`Object.values(payloadEmail) //["minnela@gmail.com","23254324","4323456"]`

Another way is `const payloadEmail=payload["email"]  //minnela@gmail.com`

Note: I am assuming that the naming convention in your sample payload i.e `payload= {"email": "minnela@gmail.com", "iat" : "23254324", "exp": "4323456"}` are exactly same as you want. Incase it has different property names then you need to change the names accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `payload.email`

Or you can use object destructuring

```js
const {email} = payload;
console.log(email); // prints minnela@gmail.com
```